# Convert UTC date&time to Europe/Lisbon

Tags: php, datetime, data-conversion

I want to convert date UTC for Europe/Lisbon, but the code I have gives me different outputs/times:

```
$datafull = "13-04-2021 08:47:13";

$date = new DateTime($datafull);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon')); 
echo $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s (e)'); 
// 13-04-2021 09:47:13 (Europe/Lisbon)

$datetime = new DateTime($datafull, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
print $datetime->format('d-m-Y H:i:s (e)');
// 13-04-2021 08:47:13 (Europe/Lisbon)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is? What do you wish to achieve?

Comment: @Grilse There are two sets of code with different outputs, the SO wants to know why these differ.

Answer (score 2):

When you supply a timezone object to the `DateTime` constructor you're telling it in what timezone the give `$datafull` is. So in:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($datafull, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
```

You say it is in *Europe/Lisbon*, and it stays there.

In the other code:

```
$date = new DateTime($datafull);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Lisbon'));
```

The default timezone is used when the `DateTime` is constructed, probably *UTC* on your server, and then you change it afterwards on the second line to  *Europe/Lisbon*, which is an hour ahead.

See: [DateTime::__construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: If $datafull represents a UTC time, then this time zone should also be specified when creating it in order to be independent of the server settings: $datetime = new DateTime($datafull, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

Comment: @NelsonSalvador As I tried to explain, the second piece of code is correct, if your server is running _UTC_.